# Why does my valid kml show as "INVALID_DOCUMENT" when loaded to google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a layer I'm trying to push to google maps.

The page is here:  http://live2.offrs.com/buyerherodev/ziptractselect.html?ZIP=20001

the data source for the kml is here: http://live2.offrs.com/buyerherodev/data/polytract.cfm?ZIP=20001&dummy=1442778330778

When I enter url for the kml in the Glados, it says that there are no errors.

However, when I load it in my page, it shows "INVALID_DOCUMENT".

I did build the kml url dynamically, but once the url is constructed, I send it to console.log to confirm it.  No issues.

Can anyone tell me where to look?  Thanks

Here's the javascript for the maps:

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

```
var boundaryurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/buyerherodev/data/polygon.cfm?TYPE=ZIP&VALUE=" + getUrlVars()["ZIP"] + "&LC=641400FF&LW=3&FC=14F11C2E&F=1&FO=1";
var tracturl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/buyerherodev/data/polytract.cfm?ZIP=" + getUrlVars()["ZIP"]+"&dummy="+(new Date()).getTime();

console.log(boundaryurl);
console.log(tracturl);

var kmlLayer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer(boundaryurl, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map,
    zindex: 0,
    clickable : false
});


var kmlLayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer(tracturl, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false
});

console.log(kmlLayer2);


google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer2,'status_changed', function() {
  if (!(kmlLayer2.getStatus() == 'OK')) {
    alert("There are no tracts.  Try again.");
    // window.location="http://domain.com/findterritory_none.cfm";
  }
});
```

kmllayer1 works with no issues.  kmllayer2 is the layer I'm speaking about today. It's kmllayer2 that is the problem.  I put the 'status_changed' listener to check for a bad kml, and here where is the error is reported.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Content-Type of the KML-file must be `application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml` , but currently it's `application/xml`

You must configure the server to return the correct Content-Type-header :

Example using the same file with correct header(using phpfiddle, I'm not sure how long it will work):

```js
function init() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 0,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    }
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://main.xfiddle.com/code_63194890.php', {
    map: map
  });


}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=init"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That was perfectly explained.  I was going bald figuring this out.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

My friends, google maps javascript API, KML layer,  limit the KML size to 10MB.
Over 10MB, you will get invalid document status on kmllayer object.

Your KML must first load to google KML service, than return back the tiled image to you.
Therefore your KML size must less than 10MB.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions

[image]